# Made mistake on Documentation Beta

Tags: support, documentation

I've made a mistake on some documentation. And I've published my documentation with a lot of modifications (unfortunately a lot of deletions). Can we access all drafts of the modification history before some documentation gets pushed on the main page? I've saved my draft every time I've modified it, it was on [Erlang documentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/erlang/drafts/133017).

This mistake was in part due to the button "cancel" on the documentation draft editing page. I was thinking this button was there to get back into "reading" mode, but unfortunately it wasn't the case. Perhaps move around this button to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 2):

You're absolutely right - that "cancel" behavior is not at all obvious.

And since this is looks to be the first revision of the topic, unfortunately there is no prior history of your draft versions. The best suggestion I can give here is to edit again to correct whatever mistakes snuck in.

Comment: doh! So my work was definitively stored in /dev/null? I hoped draft was backed up somewhere, with history/commit release... Its pretty scary! I have worked on this draft all the past week (so lot of text).

Comment: @M.Kerjouan Wait, are you talking about a draft made *after* the topic was created? I may be able to recover that. I'll take a look this afternoon.

Comment: Nope, a draft before the topic was created. ts pretty scary! I have worked on this draft all the past week (so lot of small modification). A documentation draft need history too and a way to recover it if you made mistake or change happen in released documentation.

Comment: thanks to help! It would be really great to have all my deleted work! :)

Comment: I'll see what I can find.

Comment: @M.Kerjouan I don't see any recently deleted drafts that had content in them, sorry. :( We don't have history for unpublished drafts either, only the "latest" version after the draft it saved.

Comment: doh! No problem, I will rewrite it... But a draft backup or history would be great. Not everyone push directly its contribution upstream. ;)